# Plot Historical Flot chart between two custom date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to plot historical flot chart between two custom date range, user will select date range and based on selection I will retrieve data from my database and going to plot flot chart. Retrieving data from database based on selection is completed but plotting that data in flot chart is not resulting result. Below is my code I am trying to plot

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>  
<head>    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<title>Flot Examples: Real-time updates</title>    
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>   
<script data-require="flot@0.8.2" data-semver="0.8.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>   
<script data-require="flot@0.8.2" data-semver="0.8.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>   
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<script type="text/javascript">

  
$(function() 
{ 
function GetData()
{
var data = []; 
var now = new Date().getTime(); 
var res;    
data.shift(); //to remove first item of array
var str = [[1475210230423,64.51024424527357],[1475210232423,26.131426274344072]];   
data.push(str); 
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], {series: {    
lines: {       
show: true,        
lineWidth: 1.2,        
fill: true
    }
    },        
yaxis: {        
min: 0,        
max: 100      
},       
xaxis: {
mode: "time", minTickSize: [1, "day"]
}
}    
);}
GetData();
});

  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>    
<div id="header">      
<h2>HISTORICAL CHART</h2>    
</div>
<div id="content">      
<div class="demo-container">        
<div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>     
</div>         </div>    
<div id="footer"> 
 Copyright © 2007 - 2014 IOLA and Ole Laursen 
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change this - $.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], {series: {   to this - $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {series: {  ... Remove [ ] from data.  I had to set height to placeholder div as well - <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"  style="height:300px;"></div>

Comment: @T.Shah can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html>  
    <head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
    <title>Flot Examples: Real-time updates</title>    
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>   
    <script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>   
    <script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>   
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function() 
    { 
    function GetData()
    {
    var data = []; 
    var now = new Date().getTime(); 
    var res;    
    data.shift(); //to remove first item of array
    var str = [[1475210230423,64.51024424527357],[1475210232423,26.131426274344072]];   

    data.push(str); 
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {series: {    
    lines: {       
    show: true,        
    lineWidth: 1.2,        
    fill: true
        }
        },        
    yaxis: {        
    min: 0,        
    max: 100      
    },       
    xaxis: {
    mode: "time", minTickSize: [1, "day"]
    }
    }    
    );}
    GetData();
    });


    </script>  
    </head>  
    <body>    
    <div id="header">      
    <h2>HISTORICAL CHART</h2>    
    </div>
    <div id="content">      
    <div class="demo-container">        
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"  style="height:300px;"></div>     
    </div>         </div>    
    <div id="footer">   
            Copyright © 2007 - 2014 IOLA and Ole Laursen    
    </div>  

    </body>
    </html>
```